# Unexpected Output in Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/simulator/trade/tradestock.aspx) and access this `trade_page`; however, after executing the following code, the output isn't the expected HTML code of the page.
Note that I first have to log in to Investopedia using the `login_url`, and then go to the `trading_url` to execute trades.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# create session
session = requests.Session()

login_url = 'https://investopedia.com/simulator/portfolio/'

payload = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password'
}

# get log in page
auth_page = session.get(login_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(auth_page.content, 'html.parser')

# get form
form = soup.find('form')

# get post url
post_url = form['action']

# auth
session.post(post_url, data=payload)

# parse content
trading_url = 'https://investopedia.com/simulator/trade/tradestock.aspx'
trading_page = session.get(trading_url)

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(trading_page.content, 'html.parser')

print(page_soup.prettify())
```

And here's the output of this code which isn't like the HTML code of the page when I open it from the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html class="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
   <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots"/>
   <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>
     Log In

 | Investopedia
    </title>
    <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/favicon.ico" rel="icon"/>
    <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
    <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png"/>
    <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/favicon-16x16.png" rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/png"/>
    <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/android-chrome-192x192.png" rel="icon" sizes="192x192" type="image/png">
     <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/android-chrome-512x512.png" rel="icon" sizes="512x512" type="image/png">
      <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/favicon_528x528.png" rel="icon" sizes="528x528" type="image/png"/>
      <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="60x60"/>       
      <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76"/>       
      <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120"/>   
      <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152"/>   
      <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="180x180"/>   
      <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"/>
      <link color="#333e8b" href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/safari-pinned-tab.svg" rel="mask-icon"/>
      <meta content="#333e8b" name="msapplication-TileColor"/>
      <meta content="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/mstile-144x144.png" name="msapplication-TileImage"/>
      <meta content="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/mstile-70x70.png" name="msapplication-square70x70logo"/>
      <meta content="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/mstile-150x150.png" name="msapplication-square150x150logo"/>
      <meta content="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/mstile-310x310.png" name="msapplication-square310x310logo"/>
      <meta content="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/mstile-310x150.png" name="msapplication-wide310x150logo"/>
      <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/css/base/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/css/base/base-inv-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/css/base/base-inv-form.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link href="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
         </link>
        </link>
       </link>
      </link>
     </link>
    </link>
   </meta>
  </meta>
 </head>
 <body class="page">
  <div class="container">
   <header>
    <div class="logo">
     <h1>
      <a href="https://www.investopedia.com/">
       <img alt="Investopedia" src="/auth/resources/z6l0i/login/investopedia/img/inv-logo-header.svg" title="Investopedia"/>
      </a>
     </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="subtitle-wrapper">
     <h3 class="subtitle">
      Stock Market Simulator
     </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="title-wrapper">
     <h2 class="page-title">
      Log In
     </h2>
     <div class="title-actions">
      <span>
       or
       <a href="/auth/realms/investopedia/login-actions/registration?client_id=inv-simulator-conf&amp;tab_id=zA91O-9t_fI" tabindex="6">
        create an account
       </a>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </header>
   <div class="form-wrapper">
    <form action="https://www.investopedia.com/auth/realms/investopedia/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=ZqOXzgRFs4MOQBAbk0SsGJpULk8-GNouNJsJVgELZik&amp;execution=4bd415ae-e295-49aa-bb7e-6b1d31d1d462&amp;client_id=inv-simulator-conf&amp;tab_id=zA91O-9t_fI" method="post" onsubmit="login.disabled = true; return true;">
     <div class="form-field">
      <label class="sr-only form-field__label" for="username">
       Email
      </label>
      <input autocomplete="off" autofocus="" class="form-field__input" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="1" type="text" value=""/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-field">
      <label class="sr-only form-field__label" for="password">
       Password
      </label>
      <input autocomplete="off" class="form-field__input" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2" type="password"/>       
     </div>
     <div class="btn-wrapper">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" id="login" name="login" tabindex="4" type="submit" value="Sign In"/>
     </div>
     <div class="forgot-password">
      <span>
       <a href="/auth/realms/investopedia/login-actions/reset-credentials?client_id=inv-simulator-conf&amp;tab_id=zA91O-9t_fI" tabindex="5">        
        Forgot your password?
       </a>
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="return-to-sim">
      <span>
       <a href="https://www.investopedia.com/simulator-beta/portfolio" tabindex="6">
        Looking for Simulator Beta?
       </a>
      </span>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like your session posting didn't work

Comment: I don't understand. Why?

Comment: Hard to say. I generally use Selenium to login and scrape